# Remove all files from s3 bucket using nodejs knox?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am using knox npm module to upload files to a bucket on S3. It works great. What I am not sure how to do is how to remove all the files from a bucket in one call instead of deleting one file at the time?

any idea would help...

Comment: Has nothing to do with nodejs, but in S3, you cannot delete all files at one time. You have to delete one file/object at a time, and so you have to have a loop to delete all files/objects.

Comment: @rsmoorthy: This used to be the case indeed, but has been mostly remedied via [Amazon S3 - Multi-Object Delete](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/12/amazon-s3-multi-object-deletion.html) as of December 2011 - it's still limited to 1000 objects at a time, but a significant improvement regardless of course.

Comment: @steffenOpel - Thanks! I missed that announcement. Yes, that will speed up the deletions. Last year, I had to delete more than 10M objects and it took days!

Answer (score 1):

This has not been possible in the past, however, Amazon has finally introduced [Amazon S3 - Multi-Object Delete](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_can_I_delete_large_numbers_of_objects) in December 2011:

> [Amazon S3's](http://aws.amazon.com/s3) new Multi-Object Delete gives you the ability to
>   delete up to 1000 objects from an S3 bucket with a single request.

Obviously client libraries like [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox) must add dedicated support for this API now in turn, and a respective issue does indeed exist already in knox' issue tracker (still pending as of today), see [Multi-Object Delete](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/52).

Accordingly you should monitor this issue and/or participate in the implementation :)

---

Answer (score 0):

My AwsSum library can already do multi object delete. The operation in the library is called 'DeleteMultipleObjects':

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/

You can install AwsSum via npm doing:

$ npm install awssum

There is an example here:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/blob/master/examples/amazon/s3/delete-multiple-objects.js

Hope it goes well and give me a shout if you need any assistance. :)

Comment: Recommending *only* you own stuff 8 times on you first day here is not totally appreciated. See this [FAQ on promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll go read the FAQ a bit more. However, knox is a library that is no longer maintained and therefore people get caught out. AwsSum is maintained, I try to help people and AWS is my specialty so I'd hoped StackOverflow would like that knowledge. I apologise and I'll stop answering questions in this manner.

Comment: I'm not a moderator, just a user who noticed your posts in the sites Review feature. A new user who recommends a single product in several posts on his first day, will make the spam indicator lights start to warm up. The fact that you stated up front that it is your project was good. And that your answers are still here shows that the spam filter wasn't triggered. Just wanted you to stay clear of that.